# How can I design a calendar where one can switch between month and dates within a month using FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to be able to switch between a month and dates within a month in my application using the FullCalendar plugin. How can I achieve that? I am attaching the screenshot of the UI of how I want it to somewhat look like so that the user can switch between a given month or a date within a month.

[image]

Any suggestions/guidance will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: You can't get exactly what you've show using fullCalendar but it does have an alternative way to navigate around (as well as its next/previous buttons and view change buttons which you can see on most of the demos on the website) - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-nav-links for details and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/navLinks-demo for a demo (with code provided, if you visit the codepen link in the top right corner of that page).

Comment: @ADyson I do not want the month and weekly view to be displayed for mobile version though, how can I just get dayGrid view for mobile and weekGrid view for desktop?

Comment: That's a completely different question. You'd have to use JavaScript to get the viewport size when the page loads (and optionally on resize) and use that to determine what view buttons to make available in the fullCalendar header